# Code not refreshing every few second

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi, signal-strength

I am trying to find the signal strength from wifi. I want to take 5 samples of signal strength. So, I have kept a timer that will help me make code run every second. The code I have written is shown below.

The output i get is: 
getting called 0

getting called 1

getting called 2

getting called 3

getting called 4

I do not get the sb(string builder, which i used)value.

If i remove the contents from onreceive and keep it outside the method, i get the signal strength value . But it is not getting updated every second.

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
            protected static final long TIME_DELAY = 1000;
            TextView mTextView;

            Handler handler=new Handler();  
            int count =0; String data ="";

            private static final IntentFilter FILTER = new IntentFilter(
                    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_id);

                handler.post(updateTextRunnable);

            }

      Runnable updateTextRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (count < 5) {
                        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        final WifiManager mainWifiObj;
                        mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);                 
                        class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
                        //BroadcastReceiver WifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                                 List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
                                 for (ScanResult result : wifiScanList) {
                                    if (result.SSID.equals("DAL-WPA2")) {
                                        sb.append(""+result.level);
                                    }
                                    if (result.SSID.equals("DAL")) {
                                        sb.append(""+result.level);
                                    }
                                    if (result.SSID.equals("eduroam")) {
                                        sb.append(""+result.level);
                                    }                               

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
                        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
                                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));  
                        mTextView.setText("getting called " +count + sb);
                        count++; 
                    } else {
                    }               
                        //----------------code here to send values to java server---
                          handler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);
                            }
                    };
```

I thought of using onPause and onResume method, but I think if I need to update the code every 1-2 seconds to get the new wifi strength then it would not be feasible.

Comment: Provide more code or simply extend your question. Now it is not clear how it should be understood.

Comment: @Rafik991 This is the whole code. I want to get the signal strength from wifi but i am not getting it. I want to get the answer of signal strength every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about more clear and simpler solution.
There is simply strategy do to it. You run service using system ALARM_SERVICE and get your wifi signal strength in on receive and you can store count of firing and set up the alarm service only few or five times that you mentioned.
I am sure this article would help you. [Scheduling stuff...](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)
This might be better [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788)